# Setting up VGA Passthrough on Ubuntu with KVM : error no iommu_group for device qemu-system-x86_64

Tags: debian, ubuntu, kvm, virtualization, xen

I'm trying to configure the VGA Passthrough on the Debian SID because I want to use Debian on the first monitor and Windows 7/8 on the other one. I have tried with XEN and with KVM but in both case I haven't been able to reach the goal. This is the tutorial that I'm following:

- http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/

These are the specifications of my system:

- [Motherboard](http://www.amazon.it/Gigabyte-GA-Z87-HD3-Scheda-Madre-Socket/dp/B00CXK5AY6/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1397331946&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=socket+1055)
- [CPU](http://www.amazon.it/Intel-BX80646I54670K-Processore-i5-4670K-Haswell/dp/B00CO8TBOW/ref=pd_bxgy_pc_text_b)
- [Graphics Card](http://www.amazon.it/Gigabyte-GV-N660OC-2GD-grafica-memoria-DisplayPort/dp/B0099AOAUI/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1397332420&sr=8-2&keywords=gtx+660+ti)

```
root@ziomario-Z87-HD3:/home/ziomario# lspci -nn | grep NVIDIA 01:00.0 VGA
compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] [10de:11c0] (rev a1) 01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0b] (rev a1)

root@ziomario-Z87-HD3:/home/ziomario# lspci -nn | grep VGA 00:02.0 VGA
compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
```

and this is the error I get:

```
root@ziomario-Z87-HD3:/home/ziomario# sudo /usr/vm1 
qemu-system-x86_64: 
    -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: vfio: error no iommu_group for device qemu-system-x86_64: 
    -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: Device initialization failed. qemu-system-x86_64: 
    -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: Device 'vfio-pci' could not be initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here: http://ark.intel.com/products/75048/Intel-Core-i5-4670K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz

More specifically, PCI Passthrough doesn't work on Intel processors that lack VT-d support. Many of the K-series CPU's from Intel lack this. The CPU still have VT-x support, which explains why regular KVM would work with your hardware, but not when you attempt to passthrough PCI devices such as graphics cards.